# Challenge is required to authorize the request

Tags: captcha, roblox

I am working on login api of `Roblox`. I think I am on final stage, where I call `api` for the last time. I am using funcaptcha library, I generate challenge token and I pass :

```
        "ctype": "Username",
        "cvalue": "test",
        "password": "test",
        "captchaProvider": "PROVIDER_ARKOS_LABS",
        "captchaToken": challenge.data.token,
        "challengeId": challenge.data.challengeID,
        "captchaId": fieldData.unifiedCaptchaId
```

but I still get challenge is required error, what am I doing wrong

first of all, I got `x-csrf-token`, than I had to recall the `api` to get `fieldData` for blob and such things and I finally used that response in `funcaptcha` library: https://github.com/noahcoolboy/funcaptcha and now, for the last time I call `api` where I pass body above but it still throws error: challenge is required.